# Grouping of AND statements - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been thrown back into MySQL for the first time in 5 years.  Writing up queries to run some reports. For one, I needed to find how many gallons of paint by Color ID were dispensed for the year in Division 1.  Division is found in a different table than all of our transactions.  I wrote this query -

```
SELECT m.divName, 
n.colorName, 
n.colorID,
SUM(n.gallons) as totalGallons 
FROM mfccnStore m, netTran2014 n 
WHERE (m.division = 1) AND (m.store = n.store) 
GROUP BY colorID
ORDER BY totalGallons DESC 
INTO OUTFILE '/home/Div1All.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Ran it, then to test it, I picked one of the most used colors and wrote this query -

```
SELECT m.divName, 
n.colorName, 
n.colorID,
n.gallons 
FROM mfccnStore m, netTran2014 n 
WHERE (n.colorID = "6385") AND (m.division = 1) AND (m.store = n.store) 
INTO OUTFILE '/home/DoverWhite.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

And then verified that the totals for the Color ID "6385" matched after running each query, which they did.  Great.

But now it gets a little more complex with a 3rd table needed because they want the same report, but separated by "Interior" and "Exterior" paint.

```
SELECT m.divName, 
n.colorName,
n.colorID,
SUM(n.gallons) as totalGallons
FROM mfccnStore m, netTran2014 n, netProduct p 
WHERE ((p.intExt = "INTERIOR") AND (m.division = 1) AND (m.store = n.store)) 
AND ((n.rex = p.prodNbr) AND (n.sizeCode = p.szCd))  
GROUP BY colorID
ORDER BY totalGallons DESC
INTO OUTFILE '/home/Div1Int.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

This gives me totals that are a little bit more than double the other two queries and I'm sure it must have to do with the order of my WHERE clause - and where the parentheses are being placed.  Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest using the `JOIN` syntax.  Then it reads like this:

```
SELECT m.divName,
       n.colorName,
       n.colorID,
       p.intExt
       SUM(n.gallons) totalGallons
FROM mfccnStore m
    JOIN netTran2014 n ON m.store = n.store
    JOIN netProduct p ON n.rex = p.prodNbr AND n.sizeCode = p.szCd
WHERE p.intExt IN ('INTERIOR','EXTERIOR') 
    AND m.division = 1
GROUP BY n.colorID, p.intExt
ORDER BY totalGallons DESC
```

Be careful which fields you put in the `GROUP BY` -- most RDBMS require all fields to be included that aren't included in aggregate functions.  MySQL is a little more flexible, but can return inaccurate results.

Comment: sgeddes - I will give the JOIN a shot tomorrow morning (being called to a meeting) and see if that makes the difference.  

Thank you all for your quick answers so far!

Comment: This put me closest - found out this morning also that there was one more element needed for the key on the netProduct table and all seems to be working.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to overcomplicate it.  The break down can be handled with an additional GROUP BY clause, in this case `GROUP BY p.intExt;`

Comment: I also think he cannot group on colorID here, parantheses can be removed completely when only `AND` is used.

Comment: ajacian81 - I will try adding the additional GROUP BY.

skoblajic - Why would I not be able to group by colorID on the 3rd query, since they specifically need it by color?

Would the order of my WHERE clause have anything to do with it?